# Symfony4 Equivalent to display the current route

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm looking to show the current route with symfony4. I try this:

```
{% set currentPath = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
```

but it does not work, the result is null

Thank you.

Comment: _route contains the name of the current route.  Feed it to path() to get the actual url.  Of course any parameters will be missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the current request's URI like this:

```
{% set currentPath = app.request.uri %}
```

If you want to reuse the current path and add/change some of the parameters you could do it something like this:

```
{% set routeName = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
{% set routeParams = app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'some_url_param': 'a value'}) %}

{% set currentPath = path(routeName, routeParams) %}
```